# Different penalty functions for lasso, elastic net, and ridge regression in R

Tags: r, regularized, robust

Is their a package that allows me to change the penalty function to say, Huber, or absolute value, instead of quadratic L2 norm, when using regularization such as lasso, ridge, or elastic net in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no package, as of right now, that allows to specify your own formula for the penalization. There are special packages like `hqreg` or `ncvreg` that give you some other options. The first one [hqreg](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hqreg/hqreg.pdf) allows for Huber. The second [ncvreg](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ncvreg/ncvreg.pdf) allows for minimax concave penalty (MCP) and smoothly clipped absolute deviation (SCAD).

Comment: notice that when you change the penalty from L1 to L2 norm is when you go from Lasso to Ridge, and the linear combination of those is what is called the elastic net. Hence changing the regularization path to Huber or Scad for example would not yield a Lasso or Ridge. You can also combine the L2 norm with the SCAD or MCP adding an ``elastic'' term, just as elastic net does.

Comment: I don't want to change the regularization, just the norm of the residuals. I want something like this to be my penalty : minimize {$||Ax-b||_1 + ||x||_{1}$}, or minimize {$||Ax-b||_1 + ||x||_{2}^2$},
or instead of the 1 norm, insert Huber.

(just realized latex doesn't work on this board ugh.)

Comment: minimize {||Ax-b||_2} gives LS.  minimize {$|Ax-b||_2 -||b||_2} yields ridge. The penalty term is ||b||_2. So to change the quadratic loss on the residual means changing  {||Ax-b||_2}. Is that what you want? That is the case with the hqreg, where the whole loss function is changed to the Huber loss function, you can still add a penalization term to that loss function which would regularize it. If you want a different loss function there is no one package fits all solution.

Comment: I checked it out! Hqreq has Huber, and I can change between ||x||_1 and ||x||_2 using a parameter alpha!

Thanks!